# An unexpected error has occured

Tags: error, error.htm

Can any one tell me how to customize the below error message.

By default we will get the below snapshot if we get unknown error. Is that possible to customize the below ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:

> 1. Create a page, with Content type of "Error Page" , which is now available in SharePoint 2013.
> 2. Delete out of the box Page not found error page.
> 3. Rename newly created error page with same name as default.

Comment: Do we have this feature in SharePoint 2010 ?